# How to initialize db.sqlite3 database in pythonanywhere?

Tags: django, pythonanywhere

I'm neewbie in pythonanywhere.
I've just deploy my django project and all seems to be OK except I need initialize ma database first and I don't know how to do this.
I can I get a python shell?

thanks for help

Comment: did you checked their dashboard ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can log in with SSH and then you will be able to populate your database through the command line or a shell

```
ssh <username>@ssh.pythonanywhere.com
```

Look at: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/SSHAccess

Answer (score 1):

To initialize your database in django first you want to type:

python manage.py makemigrations

then type:

python manage.py migrate

Hope this helps, if you still do not understand check the django documentation:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/tutorial01/
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/tutorial02/

read page 1 and 2 of the django tutorial

Comment: thanks both. Maybe I was not clear enought ; ) I have my database create (with migrate) but need to 'populate' my database... til now, I've open a python shell and create some records... and now I will do it with Django admin ... not really convenient

Comment: You need to create a superuser with the python shell by typing python manage.py createsuperuser than enter some credentials, next login to django admin via going to your website which i think would be 127.0.0.1:port/admin and logging in to django admin, from their you should be able to see the database with the users you creates. I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Use the credentials you made with python manage.py createsuperuser to login to the django admin page